# Lambda expression using interface in one line

Tags: java, lambda, interface

I'm learning about interfaces and I faced a problem which I cannot understand. It's about lambda expression which I learn that can be used in one line, but I've create a case, where this expression does not working and I don't know where I've made a mistake.

I have defined this interface:

```
public interface MathOperations {
    int add(int a, int b);
}
```

Next I have defined class in which I want to test this interface with adder method.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        x = adder((a, b) -> return a+b);
    }

    public static int adder(MathOperations mo){
        return mo.add(3, 5);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the line with the `x` assignment doesn't work and I cannot figure out where I've made a mistake. The compiler does not recognize the `a` and `b` variable in the `return` statement. I know that I can make this assignment with brackets but I'm curious if I can do this in one line.

Comment: adder is void but should probably return something.

Comment: `(a, b) -> return a+b` should be `(a,b) -> a+b` (or `(a,b) -> { return a+b; }`) and `adder` should return `int`. You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/ERYp9C)

Answer (score 2):

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MathOperations {
    int add(int a, int b);
}
```

Here are two ways to do what you want.

- To create a lambda, you need to specify the interface type and provide the definition of what to do with `a` and `b`.
- then you can invoke the lambda and get the value.

```
MathOperations compute = (a,b)->a+b;
x = compute.add(2,3);
System.out.println(x);
```

The above does essentially the following behind the scenes.

- Here an `anonymous class` is defined using the interface and instantiated using the `new` keyword. (the class contains the implemented method).
- Implementing the interface was standard until the concept of `FuntionalInterfaces` and lambdas were introduced in Java 8.
- Then call the `adder` method supplying the instance `mo` just created **or** call the method with the previously created `compute` lambda.

```
MathOperations mo =new MathOperations() {
                          public int add(int a,int b) {
                              return a+b;
                          }};

 System.out.println(adder(mo));
 System.out.println(adder(compute));
```

output of above three print statements

```
5
8
8
```

```
public static int adder(MathOperations mo){
    return mo.add(3, 5);
}
```

**Note:** Imo, a more versatile interface can be created by following examples from the `API functional interfaces` already defined. The name `MathOperation` is fine but the add method is too specific (and functional interfaces may only contain one `abstract method`).  So instead of having an `add` method, have a `compute` or similar method and let the `name` of the lambda dictate its `operation.`

```
MathOperation add = (a,b)->a+b;
int sum = add.compute(10,20); // 30
MathOperation sub = (a,b)->a-b;
int diff = sub.compute(10,20) // -10
```